# How to get a model instance in CodeIgniter hooks

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm tring to write a hook. It's very easy to load a model and execute some functions defined in it. jusk like:

```
$this->load->model('requestmodel');
$this->requestmodel->insert();
```

BUT in a hook, there is no `$this`, and I know this works:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('requestmodel');
$CI->requestmodel->hook_triggered_action();
```

BUT that's a hard-coded way, what I want to do is:

```
global $RTR;
$controller = $RTR->class;
$modelname = $controller.'model';
$CI->load->model($modelname);
$CI->$modename->hook_triggered_action(); // this line throws an error
```

I tried `$CI->model[$modename]->hook_triggered_action();` but it's wrong.
How?

Comment: Problem solved. The codes are all right. maybe I typed wrong at first.

Comment: Pay attention: if you defined a pre_controller hook, and in which the line `$CI =& get_instance()` will return `null` because $CI hasn't initialized yet, change the hook type to  **post_controller_constructor** to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$CI->model[$modelname]
```

This doesn't work in PHP.  `->` and `[]` are not interchangeable.

You should be able to do this however:

```
$CI->$modelname->hook_triggered_action();
```

Comment: I tried, but it also throws error.  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It shows : string(12)"requestmodel" thanks i learn a new php function. It works now, my demo question is right. Maybe there's a typing error in the first try.